# Disconnect Synchronized Data Sources

Tags: marketing-cloud

In order to remove a synchronized object connected via Marketing Cloud Connect, is the only way by removing Salesforce Integration and then repeating the Marketing Cloud Connect process to bring in the only objects that are necessary?

I have a couple of objects synced that I no longer need to have attached to Marketing Cloud and can only find a way of removing unwanted fields, but I want to remove the entire object being synced.

Any insight?

Answer (score 3):

Currently, this is not possible. You can not delete a synchronized object.

Your only option is to pause the synchronization of the objects you no longer want by going to:

Data Sources > Synchronized

- Click the entity you need to pause or resume
- Click PauseSync to stop the synchronization process

Comment: If I haven’t brought anything over in the objects yet, can I just disconnect and then re-integrate with the SF username and then sync the objects again?